# Getting this 404 error in angular application when page first time loads or when page refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, http-status-code-404, angular14

When Page first time load or refresh then this error will generate in console with current url.
This error will generate in development server but not generate in localhost.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUAGt.jpg)

When I click on abcd:1 atright corner then below sources will open
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B2go.jpg)

Let me know if any solution for this error

I tried with replace <base href="/"> with <base href="./"> in index.html but still not fix this issue.
Also try with remove dynamic path in routing.module file.

Comment: <base href="/"> is OK. How are you using ng build?

Answer (score 1):

You could enable hash routing can help avoid 404 errors when refreshing the page.

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Or if you could check if on that server URL rewrite is enabled: all URLs which is not pointing to index.html, should be redirected to it. This is a common issue for SPA's.